# Excel vba get a column's range with only column's number

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get a range of cells from a column number `k` with rows from `e` to `f`. Variables may vary.

Is there a way to do so **without converting column's number to a string and doing other string manipulations**?

So far that's what I found:

```
Sub testRanges()
    Dim tempRange As Range
    Set tempRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Columns(2)
  '  tempRange.Select  'it works fine
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For Each cell In tempRange.Cells
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Cells(i, 7).value = cell.value 'works
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

However I don't know the syntax to make it pick only rows 5-80

```
Dim e as Integer;
Dim f As Integer;
Dim k As Integer;

e=5;
f=80;
k=6;
```

in sixth `Columns(k)`. Any ideas?

Comment: E and F are column references, not rows.  What do you mean by picking rows e to f in k?

Comment: @ Karl Kristjansson See edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: you're interested in Cells 5 and 6 of column 2. You could use:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup")
    For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(6, 2))
        '...
    Next
End With
```

Any number above can be replaced by a numeric variable, typically of type Long.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correct you want the range to be F5:F80.(unless you have 1R1C table format)

```
Sub testy()
  Dim e As Integer
  Dim f As Integer
  Dim k As Integer

  e = 5
  f = 80
  k = 6


  Range(Cells(e, k), Cells(f, k)).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to take the intersection of rows and columns, in VBA the command for this is `Intersect()`.

Try this:

```
Sub Test
    Dim k as range
    set k =intersect(Rows("3:4"),columns("E"))
    k.select
End Sub
```